# retrieve GPU info in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just need to assign the GPU info of a current system to a label.I have successfully assigned values of systemname,CPU,RAM etc.But i need to find a way to do so with graphic card.
Any ideas?

here is the code:

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher MOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"); 
        foreach (ManagementObject MO in MOS.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessorID  :" + MO["ProcessorID"]);
            lblProcessorID.Text = MO["ProcessorID"].ToString();
            label3.Text = MO["Name"].ToString();
            label2.Text = MO["Description"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what gpu info? From which system? Server or client? Show what you have got so far.

Comment: Yeah. I wonder you got labels of CPU and RAM already - please post code. As in: I think you have not what you think you have.

Comment: I just need to display the graphic card info...lets say RAM of graphic card OF Clients computer.

Comment: @TomTom - Done.Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to learn the basics how a web application works. What you do is get the info from the SERVER. There is no way to do that on the client because of that pesky thing called "security". I know, totally overrated - we all want random people from the internet to hack around in our computer.

YOU use a management framework on the server to pull up data from the server.

Now, if you still want to do that on the server then - ah - use the following link:

[Retrieving graphics/sound card information on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481179/retrieving-graphics-sound-card-information-on-windows)

which shows how to get the info from WMI.

Not exactly super complicated - you must have like totally not read any documentation to overlook that. The relevant "table" is "Win32_VideoController", Quite obvious when you go through the different WMI tables ;)

Comment: I dont think m gonna use this as a web application or something.Its just an application which will be installed on the clients computer and there they can retrieve their system info.Not possible?

Comment: Sure possible. But this is another question. And please speak english. Gonna? Like "I failed school gonna"?

Comment: *Going To.But thats what my question is.I just want to retrieve clients info on a click.I dont see how is it different from what i asked.

Comment: Professional behavior. And I did link the answer - you just must read it.